# Как разместить 2 дива под друг другом вертикально?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class:"1">
</div>
<div class:"2">
</div>
```

Как заCSSсить так, что бы они оказались под друг другом (вертикально)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разделять атрибут от параметра должен знак равно (`=`), а не двоеточие (`:`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дайте родительскому элементу:

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

---

Полный пример:

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.parent {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.parent div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="1">
    <h1>
      1
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="2">
    <h1>
      2
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, написать и html, в котором есть classы

Comment: Дополнил код, проверяйте

Comment: @TaskeMiura таким образом они встанут в линию, а не в столбец, как хочет автор

Comment: @Михаил Камахин, таким образом весь контент в контейнере не будет в колонку. Спорить не буду, по мне оба варианта верны.

Comment: @TaskeMiura вставил ваш код в сниппет stackoverflow, смотрите сами

Comment: @Михаил Камахин добавил flex-wrap

Answer (score 1):

Они и сами по себе друг под другом встают.